# Why isn't this if statement returning True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that counts how many times a band has played a song from a webpage of all their setlists. I have grabbed the webpage and converted all the songs played into one big list so all I wanted to do was see if the song name was in the list and add to a counter but it isn't working and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've tried using the count function instead and that didn't work

```py
sugaree_counter = 0

link = 'https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mleone/gdead/dead-sets/' + year + '/' + month+ '-' + day + '-' + year + '.txt'

    page = requests.get(link)
    page_text = page.text
    page_list = [page_text.split('\n')]
    print(page_list)
```

This code returns the list:

```
[['Winterland Arena, San Francisco, CA (1/2/72)', '', "Truckin'", 'Sugaree',
  'Mr. Charlie', 'Beat it on Down the Line', 'Loser', 'Jack Straw',
  'Chinatown Shuffle', 'Your Love At Home', 'Tennessee Jed', 'El Paso',
  'You Win Again', 'Big Railroad Blues', 'Mexicali Blues',
  'Playing in the Band', 'Next Time You See Me', 'Brown Eyed Women',
  'Casey Jones', '', "Good Lovin'", 'China Cat Sunflower', 'I Know You Rider',
  "Good Lovin'", 'Ramble On Rose', 'Sugar Magnolia', 'Not Fade Away',
  "Goin' Down the Road Feeling Bad", 'Not Fade Away', '',
  'One More Saturday Night', '', '']]
```

But when I do:

```py
sugaree_counter = int(sugaree_counter)

if 'Sugaree' in page_list:
    sugaree_counter += 1

print(str(sugaree_counter))
```

It will always be zero.

It should add 1 to that because 'Sugaree' is in that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page_list is a list of lists, so you need two for loops to get the pages, you need to do

```
for page in page_list:
    for item in page:
        sugaree_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum()` and list expressions:

```py
sugaree_counter = sum([page.count('Sugaree') for page in page_list])
```